# SQL Server Compact database file decrypt unlock

Tags: sql-server-ce, encryption, password-encryption

I got an unique database local file name database.db

This was generated with SQL Server Comptact edition, but it is in encrypted format.

Does anyone knows a tool to decrypt the password, or try to decode it with any brute force system?

I have the libraries / dll of the ASP.NET software which opens the file. If I will decompile it, can I find the password as a static string value?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find the connection string if you have the source and config files. Or you can try SqlCeConnection.Open from code - brute force.
I have never encountered a Tool for this.

Comment: Thanks. I found something for the connection, but password is in a variable like Constants.ParamDataBaseSqlServerKey ...

Comment: That you should be able to locate in the Constants class

Comment: Yeah ! I found it, with [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) I opened all the libraries, and with right button function : Go To Member, I found the password to access the SQL Server Compact file. Thanks for advices.

Comment: Doesn't sound very secure!

Comment: @ErikEJ I was referring to the comment that said the password was stored in the code and retrieved through decompilation.

Comment: @Ronnie - got it - now that's how NOT to do it :-)